# how to change the date displayed on a datepickerdialog?

Tags: android, datepickerdialog

I have the following widget in my app. Where it says set date is it possible to replace this with the day of week, day of month, month and year. eg  wed 07 Nov 2012?

I'm running Android 4 on htc whereas i know if i run the same code on Android 2.3.3 the the date is displayed how i want it.

[image]

.[update1]

```
@Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
        case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
            // set date picker as current date

            return new DatePickerDialog(this,2 ,datePickerListener, year, month, day);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

.[update2]

```
@Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
        case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
            // set date picker as current date

            final DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateInstance(0);
              final Calendar mCal = Calendar.getInstance();
               // Create a date picker dialog
               DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this,2,datePickerListener, year, month, day){
                   @Override
                   public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year,int month, int day){
                       mCal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                        mCal.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
                        mCal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);
                       setTitle(df.format(mCal.getTime()));
                   }
               };
            return datePickerDialog;
            //return new DatePickerDialog(this,2 ,datePickerListener, year, month, day);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I did it with following code.. You will have to change according to your requirement.

```
dPicker.init((previouslyEnteredDate.getYear() + 1900),
                        previouslyEnteredDate.getMonth(),
                        previouslyEnteredDate.getDate(), null);
```

Comment: hi i've updated the post with the code that creates the datepickerdialog. I don't use datepicker as you are suggesting. thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to initialize it with the current date as a reminder of what today is (or at least don't need it to change as the user interacts with the picker) you can do it by creating a temporary variable and calling the [`setTitle(CharSequence)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html#setTitle%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) method on it (since `DatePickerDialog` extends `AlertDialog`)

for example:

```
case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
      // set date picker as current date
      DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(this, 2, datePickerListener,
                                                  year, month, day);
      dpd.setTitle("Today is: " + year + "-" + (month + 1) + "-" + day);
      return dpd;
```

Okay, I got a bit lazy with the formatting, there, obviously, but I hope you get the basic idea.

If you want the title to update as they are changing the date on the picker, that gets more involved, but I can't imagine that's what you're going for (unless the point is to see the day of the week in context as they are changing it?).  If it is, let me know and I'll elaborate.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. I've updated my post to include the code amendments. It works fine apart from the date is not set in the title until the user interacts with the widget. How can i initialize the widget? Thanks